# Why can't my AVAudioPlayer detect if it's playing or not?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I have been trying to figure out a way to pause my audio with a button (very simple, just on click backgroundMusic.stop()) but it doesn't pause. With the code below the idea is that it runs from the opening of the app but when I load the scene again it won't play on top of the previous track. All the code below is doing is printing 'play' every time I load the scene and I get multiple tracks playing over each other so it seems it is unable to detect is the audio is playing or not. This is my first time using audio in xcode so I'm unfamiliar with it. I am using xCode 7.0.1 and Swift 2.

Inside my ViewController class but outside my ViewDidLoad:

```
func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer?  {
    //1
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    //2
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    // 3
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("Player not available")
    }

    return audioPlayer
}
```

In my ViewDidLoad:

```
    if let backgroundMusic = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("Kawai Kitsune", type:"mp3") {
        self.backgroundMusic = backgroundMusic
    }
    if backgroundMusic != nil {
        if backgroundMusic?.playing == false{
            backgroundMusic?.volume = 0.1
            backgroundMusic?.play()

            print("play")
        }
        else {
            print("playing")

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your `AVAudioPlayer` object at class level and then try. It should work!

Something like this:

```
class MyController : UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString)  {
        //1
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("Kawai Kitsune", type:"mp3")

        if self.audioPlayer != nil {
            if self.audioPlayer?.playing == false {
                self.audioPlayer?.volume = 0.1
                self.audioPlayer?.play()

                print("play")
            }
            else {
                print("playing")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! To clarify, you are saying that I need to put my 2nd bit of code outside my viewDidLoad. If so, how am I going to play the audio when the app opens? @Abhinav

Comment: Really sorry, I was unable to connect to the internet for a while. I tried what you did (copied and pasted, obviously changing audioplayer to backgroundMusic) but it still only says 'play' and the audio plays on top of each other. @Abhinav

Comment: Why don't you try stopping the audio and then play it. I shall try running it tomorrow with my test app. Let me know if stopping and then playing works for you.

Comment: Now I have this  if self.backgroundMusic != nil {
            if self.backgroundMusic?.playing == false {
                self.backgroundMusic?.volume = 0.1
                self.backgroundMusic?.stop()
                self.backgroundMusic?.play()
                
                print("play")
            }
            else {
                print("playing")
                
            }
        }
and it doesn't work now either. Thanks for your help, it seems like a very strange problem. @Abhinav

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with it? @Abhinav

Comment: Yes! I made an empty view controller and made that the first view controller that appears. In the viewDidAppear I first made it play the sound and then I automatically triggered a segue to the real first scene(main menu). In this way I was able to trigger the background music at the opening of the app and never again(because you would never enter that empty view controller again. I kind of circumvented the entire problem and cheated but it works so I'm happy. Thanks again for your help! @Abhinav

Comment: Great and sorry my system got crashed so I could not respond to you. Really happy you made it :-), cheers!